# How to install pythonnet in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, msbuild, python.net

I tried to install pythonnet in vs code by input

```
pip install pythonnet
```

in terminal and the error come up.

I also tried to git install

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet -U --force
```

and `cd` to the dir and run `python setup.py install`

And I am sure that my setuptool and wheel is up to date

any easy way to install the `pythonnet`?

thank for anyone help !

error:

````
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python> pip install pythonnet
Collecting pythonnet
  Using cached pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
  Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-l_p_t2zy'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\
  Complete output (76 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  ?????? https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ ????
  ?????? NuGet.exe 4.1.0?
  ???? NuGet.exe ? 5.4.0?
  ?????
  Cannot find the specified version of msbuild: '14'
  MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.0.462.64354' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin'.   
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk. [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\src\runtime\Python.Runtime.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk. [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\src\testing\Python.Test.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk. [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\src\embed_tests\Python.EmbeddingTest.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk. [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\src\console\Console.csproj]
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(321,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk. [C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\src\clrmodule\clrmodule.csproj]

  ??: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.
  Restoring NuGet package UnmanagedExports.1.2.7.
  Restoring NuGet package NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0.
  Restoring NuGet package NUnit.3.7.1.
  Adding package 'NUnit.3.7.1' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'
  Adding package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'
  Adding package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'
  Added package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'
  Added package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'
  Added package 'NUnit.3.7.1' to folder 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\packages'

  NuGet Config files used:
      C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

  Feeds used:
      C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

  Installed:
      3 package(s) to packages.config projects
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 24, in <module>
      from pycparser import c_ast, c_parser
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycparser'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\setup.py", line 623, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\setup.py", line 610, in run
      return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\setup.py", line 298, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, geninterop, interop_file])
    File "c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\User\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\python.exe', 'tools\\geninterop\\geninterop.py', 'src\\runtime\\interop38.cs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
  Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
    Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-msg167e6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pythonnet'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-35qtcmee\pythonnet\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]       
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-35qtcmee\\pythonnet\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-msg167e6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pythonnet' Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: There is a closed issue in the Github page of `pythonnet`: [#609](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/609). Maybe you can check it out.

Comment: @vahdet I think this is other error, find out i have no "Roslyn" file under "bin"
how can i modify the system reading path ? or just create a file myself cause i saw many TARGETS file under "bin"